# Passing a function name to setHeader() method in mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using a [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) - PHP class which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML.

There's the method [`setHeader()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setheader.html) which get a string parameter. I tried to pass `{DATE h:i:s}` and it is working, but I have created my own function, lets say, `GET`, which is not working.

Comment: could you please *share* the code in question?

Comment: added references and re-phrased the question, so it's more clear.